# Delete duplicates from an ArrayList using compareTo

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

I'm trying to make an ArrayList of objects Edge, without any duplicates :

```
public class Edge implements Comparable<Edge>{
    private int vertex1, vertex2;
    //constructor, getter ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Edge o) {
        if (vertex1 == o.getVertex1() && vertex2 == o.getVertex2()) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I thought that using a HashSet who doesn't accept duplicates will work but I was wrong :

```
ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
//fill list (with possible duplicates)

//delete duplicates
Set<Edge> hs = new HashSet<Edge>();
hs.addAll(edges);
edges.clear();
edges.addAll(hs);
```

This method works with ArrayList of String, Integer, but I don't understand why it doesn't works for this case.

Sorry for my english, I'm french.

Comment: You have to override `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You have two options:

- override `equals()` and `hashcode()` if you want to use a `HashSet`, or
- use a `TreeSet` which relies on `compareTo` to determine the presence of duplicates.

So in your code, just replace `Set<Edge> hs = new HashSet<Edge>();` with:

```
Set<Edge> hs = new TreeSet<Edge>();
```

and it will work as expected. Note that the fact that your `compareTo` is not consistent with `equals` may create other issues, so only do this if you understand what you are doing. More info in the javadoc of [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) and [TreeSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your objects has different hash so `HashSet` put it in different brackets.

When you override `equals` you should override `hashCode` too.

Equal objects must have same `hash`

Answer (score 0):

Override `hashCode` and `equals` method

```
public class Edge implements Comparable<Edge>{
    private int vertex1, vertex2;
    //constructor, getter ...
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Edge o) {
        if (vertex1 == o.getVertex1() && vertex2 == o.getVertex2()) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + vertex1;
        result = prime * result + vertex2;
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Edge other = (Edge) obj;
        if (vertex1 != other.vertex1)
            return false;
        if (vertex2 != other.vertex2)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one :

```
public List<Edge> removeDuplicates(List<Edge> fullList) {

    List<Edge> noDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Edge edge : fullList){
        if (!fullList.contains(edge))
            noDuplicates.add(edge);
    }

    return noDuplicates;
}
```

For me work fine to remove duplicates objects from a list!

Comment: (1) How can that work? each `edge` in your for-loop is in the list, by construction and (2) you have turned an O(n) algo into O(n^2), which is not a good idea if the list is not small.